# Country Dropdown based access in Tridion Content setup

Tags: 2013, dd4t, keyword

Requirement: In my website, there is a dropdown, which holds country list. By Click any country it will check if the country is authorized (based on some logic) and then will open some content(multimedia items like pdfs /static content).

For this, In my main component , i have used one category (countrylist) which holds list of keyword countries as metadata field (multivalued check boxes). Now, Why multi-valued check boxes --> This allows me to check for authorized logic (if any country is checked or not can be set from Tridion).

Now, if it is authorized then it will open another component(multimedia/content) content in same or new window.

For this, a new component (content component) is designed with two fields. Field 1, will hold country name (from the same category), this is to map the country name in the metadata field's  checked value of the main component. And then a component link to show the content.

Is this a good approach or feasible? Is there any other suitable way of doing this? Keyword metadata or anything.

We are using DD4T at the front end, so keeping in that mind i thought of the above approach.Thanks for your help.

Comment: hey sorry, but i am unable to understand your requirement. you already using metadata of country on the component for tagging.

Comment: I have to agree with Raj, as it is, your question is not clear to me. Maybe it helps if you start editing your question (note the spelling mistakes, it looks like you were in quite a rush writing it down, that usually doesn't help) and try to reword it and make your problem a bit more clear? Please note you should stick to one question only, you can always add follow up questions later on, but this site is all about practical and answerable questions, don't just throw down a complex (multi-question) problem and expect an answer.

Comment: Sorry for putting some question content not clear to you, i will try to simplify the requirement.

Comment: Any approach that works can (subjectively) be considered "feasible approach". Are you stuck somewhere? If so, please share the code of where you are stuck. That will make it a lot clearer what help you are looking for. If you are just looking to chat with someone about your approach, the tridion stackexchange chat might be a more suitable place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating this type of functionality it helps to model your content's relationships.

You basically have two options for relationships:

1. **Direct relationship**, as seen in Tridion's Component Presentation on a Page or Component links
2. **Indirect relations**, typically created by tagging items with Taxonomy (Keywords set in Component fields)

Your Web and Tridion content models include:

- Drop-down `CountryList` as a list in delivery
- Tridion Category with a direct (1:1) relationship to the drop-down
- Information to display for each drop-down/Keyword selection

You need to confirm:

- Is the information *directly* related to the CountryList? If it's strongly related in a 1:1 relationship, then you could place the metadata *in* the Keywords. This is good for things like language culture, currencies, or geographic location.
- Do you have more than one item to display and do authors need to control order?

  - If only one item or order doesn't matter, Taxonomy or metadata selections on the presented components work.
  - If authors need to control placement or order, then you should consider multi-value links or component presentations on a page.

You could even use Profiling and Personalization if the number of CPs is reasonable enough. I would avoid having the delivery approach completely control the Tridion content model. The extra keyword could be redundant already have much of that info.

Instead of:
Keyword1 (Keyword) <-> Keyword1 (in a "lookup" component) -> Component1

Why not intead:
Component1 with a text field set to Category?

Also if a user can't access certain values in the drop-down list, consider not letting them choose or even see them.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation Alvin, whoch seems very logical. I will look into the approach as you have stated and will let you know for any help.

Comment: Cheers. A "hallway" test is a great way to see what makes sense for your authors. Since it takes moment to setup and try schemas, having your next passing colleague try a setup, even before templating it, will likely improve your "back-end" (CMS) design. :-)